# Adding PictureBoxes during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I am in the process of creating a small WindowsForm Dice Game for a school project and one of the specifications is to read in a text file of obstacles with their positions and how many spaces to move back by. I have successfully read the text file containing this information into a jagged array and I now need to generate PictureBoxes to act as obstacles. The code compiles fine and everything seems to be working but the PictureBoxes are not showing up in my form. The x and y values are correct and inside the form. The if statement is checking whether the obstacle is sending the player forwards or backwards and changing the image accordingly.

```
int obstacleX = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Location.X) - 14;
int obstacleY = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Location.Y) + 6;
PictureBox obstacle = new PictureBox();
if (Library.GlobalVariables.obstacleStats[i][1] < 0)
{
    obstacle.Image = Properties.Resources.badObstacle;
}
else
{
    obstacle.Image = Properties.Resources.goodObstacle;
}
obstacle.Location = new Point(obstacleX, obstacleY);
obstacle.Size = new Size(17, 17);
obstacle.Show(); 
this.Controls.Add(obstacle);
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Thanks for your help,

Josh

Comment: You should redraw the screen to show the new objects.

Comment: How do I redraw the screen? this.Refresh() does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Append obstacle.BringToFront(), in case the pbox is overlapped by another control.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd try first adding the control, and then showing it; how can show work if it's not added to a container yet?

Comment: Add `obstacle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` to have a try?

Comment: Thanks @Iron, that seems to have worked...

Comment: Not at all, it's my pleasure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture may not be completely displayed, just set the `SizeMode` to have a try:

```
obstacle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `obstacle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` solved the problem.

Here is the final code for those interested:

```
int obstacleX = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Location.X) - 14;
int obstacleY = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Location.Y) + 6;
PictureBox obstacle = new PictureBox();
if (Library.GlobalVariables.obstacleStats[i][1] < 0)
{
    obstacle.Image = Properties.Resources.badObstacle;
}
else
{
    obstacle.Image = Properties.Resources.goodObstacle;
}
obstacle.Location = new Point(obstacleX, obstacleY);
obstacle.Size = new Size(17, 17);
obstacle.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
this.Controls.Add(obstacle);
obstacle.Show();
obstacle.BringToFront();
```

Thanks for the help,

Josh